# How do I run a console app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, console, console-application

I'm trying to deploy a ruby (**NOT** rails) app to Heroku. My procfile is laid out like so:

```
console: bundle exec ruby main.rb
```

However, my app never actually launches. The logs on the system are all quiet, I see nothing resembling any error output.

If I run the command as shown in the procfile on my local system, my program launches and runs exactly as it should.

More interestingly, if I run `heroku console`, the app immediately fires up on the console itself. Looks like some interaction with the procfile? How do I launch my app automatically without being connected to the console on Heroku and have the stdout captured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the `console` entry to run, you need to [scale it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling):

```
$ heroku ps:scale console=1
```

That said, Heroku uses `console` to mean "the thing that I use to perform certain interactive administrative functions on my application", which is why `heroku console` runs the `console` Procfile entry *and* provides you a bidirectional pipe. You seem to have a different meaning -- "the thing which I need to always run to perform certain background tasks". (`web` also has special meaning to Heroku -- the routing mesh will send HTTP requests to `web` processes.) I would therefore also rename this, so that `console` still means "console".

You could choose `main`, for parity with `main.rb`, but instead I would encourage you to think about what this component actually does and instead give both the Procfile entry and `main.rb` a descriptive label.

Comment: Aha! I hadn't read far enough into Heroku's documentation yet; following the starter guide made it sound like the Procfile entries had to be static names that were somehow meaningful to Heroku's backend (web defines a web dyno, so it follows that Console...)

I renamed Console to Bot and then scaled it to 1 - all is well with the world. I'd like that to be done (the scale = 1 part) on deploy, but I can research that. Much thanks!

Comment: Your process formation is an application property that survives deploys. Heroku defaults to `web=1` (and everything else 0), but once you set `web=0` + `bot=1`, it'll stay like that until you change it again.

Comment: No amount of googling is turning this up.. where do I set this option? @willglynn

Comment: Er, `heroku ps:scale web=0 bot=1`?

Comment: Oh - misunderstood. Though that was an option I could set in a file to have it be done automatically. Next best thing I guess would be a post commit hook in git

Comment: I'm trying to explain that Heroku remembers your process formation. You say `heroku ps:scale web=0 bot=1` and it'll run 0 web processes and 1 bot process. You don't need to do anything. Push, and it'll shut down your app and restart it exactly as it was, whether that's one process or a hundred.